# How to create Bootstrap columns all with same width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have more than 12 columns in the row which makes the columns stack vertically, but the top ones have different size compared to bottom ones.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md"></div>
    <div class="col-md"></div>
    <div class="col-md"></div>
    <div class="col-md"></div>
    <div class="col-md"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to have responsive (allow grow) columns but all columns should carry same width.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried col-md-4?

Comment: add an empty one at the end that is invisible

Comment: @TemaniAfif Please don't advice ugly fixes :)

Comment: @Wimanicesir it's not an *ugly*, it's a *working* fix (simplified example: https://jsfiddle.net/0cpztxna/1/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try insert a col-md-4 with no content or insert only 2 col-md-4 on a row, See if this help you. Look at full screen. (Modified the answer with the help of the comments)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      3
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     2
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-4" id="last-column">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is `md-4`? there is no such class

Comment: @FlavioCaruso Adding an empty would be a dirty fix, but what about small screen sizes where only one column appears at a time and then I will have last column as empty space?

Comment: You can add an id to the last column and a display none, i will change the Answer to show you.

Comment: I thought bootstrap supports not needing the empty one? https://jsfiddle.net/sbp8zdon/

Comment: @MaihanNijat no need media query, bootstrap classes already contain the needed ones  to show/hide element on different screen sizes

Answer (score 1):

You don't need custom CSS for this. You should use the already defined responsive [bootstrap classes for displaying](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/). Also another .row is not needed but could be useful for another row.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      4
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      5
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 d-none d-lg-block">
      6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```