# How to align the grid system html/css?

Tags: html, css, angular

I am writing app in Angular. I want that cards be displayed sequentially. Now, when the number of cards is less than the full row, the cards move to the right, which looks bad. How can I fix it?

[image]

---

---

[image]

Html file:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 3%; max-width: 2800px;">
        <div *ngFor="let order of orders" class="col mb-5">
            <div class="card text-center bg-white rounded shadow-sm">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{orderStatuses[order.status]}}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text small text-muted">{{order._id}}</p>
                    <p class="card-text">Kwota: {{order.sum}} zł</p>

                    <div class="buttons box px-3 py-2 mt-4">
                        <button type="button" class="btn additional effect 
                                 [routerLink]="order._id">
                            <strong>Sprawdź</strong>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS file:

```
.box {
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: space-around;
  } 
  .card {
  max-width: 325px;
  }
```

Comment: ```class="col mb-5"``` >>```class="col-mb-5"```

Comment: Then there are no margins, and the box class that centers the view stops working. Is there any other option to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create Bootstrap columns all with same width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56024390/how-to-create-bootstrap-columns-all-with-same-width)

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you :)